# Updating your branch with the latest changes from master branch

Tags: git, github, branch

Suppose you make a branch called  `test`  from a called branch  `master` . Then the  `master`  branch is updated with some changes. What is the best way to update your branch  `test`  with the latest  `master`  branch without overwriting your changes in  `test` ?

Basically, I did the following:

```
git clone git@project.git 
git checkout -b test
```

Make changes to  `test` . But now  `master`  has been updated. So when I do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "updated test"
git push origin test
```

it is working with the older version of `master`. How do I use the newest version?

Comment: You either merge or rebase. Let me find the dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rebase your branch on top of the remote `master`.

First, fetch the least changes:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then rebase your branch:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: Do I do this within the <code> test </code> branch?

Comment: You have to run these commands after checkout the test branch

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
git pull origin master
```